# Can I add a newer network manger to 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, network-manager

I need a newer version of Network manager on 18.04 as far as I can tell there are many but they aren't (for good reason?) being included in the distro.

1. Can I add a newer version to the apt and have it all work automatically? I'm sure I could do it manually, but I'd prefer to use apt.
2. Anyone know if its safe?

Comment: Why not tell us what your problem is, instead of your diagnosis that a different NM is required?

Comment: "21-02-25 00:22:49 ERROR (MainThread) [supervisor.dbus.network] Version '1.10.6' of NetworkManager is not supported!"

Comment: Please see my quick answer. If that doesn't work, reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem that might require reinstalling Ubuntu. But, let's try this first...

`sudo apt update` # update the software databases

`sudo apt upgrade` # make sure all updates have been installed

`sudo apt install --reinstall network-manager` # reinstall NM

`reboot` # reboot the system